# Can I use Where Clause like this for my query.. help me

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DATE(dateissued) AS date
     , SUM(amount) AS total_collection1 
 Where accountcodeid = '44'
     , SUM(amount) AS total_collection2   
 Where accountcodeid = '40'
  FROM payment
 GROUP 
    BY dateissued 
 ORDER 
    BY dateissued DESC 
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: [No](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).  Include some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Or consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but

```
SUM(case when accountcodeid = '44' then amount else 0 end) AS total_collection1
```

is valid

Comment: Yeah thanks so much